# SELECT clause with group by expression

Tags: sql, oracle

Table Name : TEST

```
//TEST
A#      NAME    
------------
1       CHIRS
2       MAY
3       JOHN

//APPLIES
A#        P#
---------------------
1         HELLO
2         YES
1         HAPPY
```

When ever i use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TEST t INNER JOIN APPLIES ap
on t.A#=ap.A# WHERE count(*)>1;
```

I want to show display only 1 or more records found in APPLIES where TEST.A#=APPLEIS.A#

Expected output:

```
A#      NAME
-------------
1       CHIRS
```

Comment: "Give error" --- do we need to guess what error it is? `GROUP BY t.*` --- what did you want to express by this? `t.*` **is not** an expression

Comment: Show your expected output with sample data..

Comment: 1. Use `GROUP BY`, not `DISTINCT`; 2. Use `HAVING` not `WHERE` to filter after the aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indicate the column names individuallly in your code. Try this:

```
SELECT t.A#, t.NAME, t.ADDRESS, t.ACOMMENT
FROM TEST t INNER JOIN APPLIES ap
on t.A#=ap.A# GROUP BY t.A#, t.NAME, t.ADDRESS, t.ACOMMENT;
```

Comment: i tried byt the acomment is in LONG type. i cant group it.

Comment: So you should remove it from sql, no?

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by all the fields is essentially the same as using `distinct`:

```
SELECT     DISTINCT * 
FROM       test t 
INNER JOIN applies ap ON t.A#=ap.A#;
```

Comment: But it stated that this is not a single group function. how?